# Simple DNS Configuration on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: internal-dns, ubuntu-18.04

Can't seem to get past a configuration error while configuring a simple DNS nameserver on Ubuntu 18.04 with Bind9.

named.conf.local file is pretty straigt-forward:

```
zone "mynameserver.local" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.mynameserver.local";
        notify no;
};
zone "10.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.10.0.10.reverse";
        notify no;
};
```

My Forward File:

```
$TTL 3D
@       IN      SOA     ns1.mynameserver.local. dns1.mynameserver.local. (
                        20190228                ; serial (today's edit date)
                        8H                      ; refresh in seconds
                        2H                      ; retry in seconds
                        4W                      ; expire in seconds
                        1D)                     ; minimum in seconds
;
                NS      ns1                     ; Inet address of name server
ns1             A       10.0.10.235
gw              A       10.0.10.1               ; Network Gateway
                TXT     "Network Gateway"       ; Network Gateway
mail            A       10.0.10.245             ; Mail Gateway
```

Reverse:

```
$TTL 3D
@       IN      SOA     ns1.mynameserver.local. dns1.mynameserver.local. (
                        20180228                ; serial number
                        8H                      ; Refresh
                        2H                      ; Retry
                        4W                      ; Expire
                        1D)                     ; Minimum TTL
                NS      ns1.mynameserver.local

1               PTR     gw.mynameserver.local
245             PTR     mail.mynameserver.local
202             PTR     intergyserver.mynameserver.local
```

`named-checkconf` comes back clean.

`named-checkzone ns1.mynameserver.local db.mynameserver.local` comes back ok

`named-checkzone 10.0.10.in-addr.arpa db.10.0.10.reverse` errors with:

```
zone 10.0.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: NS 'ns1.mynameserver.local.10.0.10.in-addr.arpa' has no address records (A or AAAA)
zone 10.0.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

What is it that I am missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add a dot at the end of `ns1.mynameserver.local` (`ns1.mynameserver.local.`) in `/etc/bind/db.10.0.10.reverse`, wherever applicable.

With dot, the name is absolute. Without dot, the name is relative to the zone (ie. `ns1.mynameserver.local.10.0.10.in-addr.arpa` as your error message points out).

The complete config should look like that:

```
$TTL 3D
@       IN      SOA     ns1.mynameserver.local. dns1.mynameserver.local. (
                        20180228                ; serial number
                        8H                      ; Refresh
                        2H                      ; Retry
                        4W                      ; Expire
                        1D)                     ; Minimum TTL
                NS      ns1.mynameserver.local.

1               PTR     gw.mynameserver.local.
245             PTR     mail.mynameserver.local.
202             PTR     intergyserver.mynameserver.local.
```

Note that I have added dots after all `PTR` records too. Remember about this dot also when making `CNAME` records to external domains in forward zone, otherwise your record will point to something like `external.com.mynameserver.local`